# Bluemix Mobile data query

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud

I am using:

`query.find().continueWith(new Continuation<List<Item>, Void>()`

However, this query just fetches me the list of single field in the database. Can you please let me know what construct do I need to use for query to fetch complete record (multiple fields in one row/ record)?

Comment: Can you please specify the exact Bluemix service that you are using? - Thanks!

Comment: I am using Mobile data service of Bluemix

Comment: I need to ask for a bit of clarification please.  Are you writing a native or hybrid app?  Or are you writing server-side code to access this data?

Comment: It looks like you're writing an Android app using the Bolts framework.  Can you append a bit more code from around this query to help me understand better how you're building your query please?  As of yet, I don't see the relationship specifically to the Mobile Data service.

Comment: Hi John,First of all Thank you for going through my query. Also, thank you for writing back. Yes, you are correct that I am trying to access data from my mobile application. I have a small table which has Six (6) fields in it. I have inserted data into it. Now I want to read all the data and then edit the same and save it back to the table. Unfortunately when I use IBMQuery<Item> query = IBMQuery.queryForClass(Item.class);
query.find().continueWith(new Continuation<List<Item>, Void>() , it returns all the records for only One (1) field value, and not all the records with all field values.

Comment: Hi John, got a resolution from Vijay. Using the class object, and the getter method, value for each record can be retrieved individually. The syntax isItem itobj : objects

Comment: Hi John, got a resolution from Vijay. Using the class object, and the getter method, value for each record can be retrieved individually. The syntax is as follows:  Item itobj : objects and the second line is itobj.getterMethod();